# show data from database inside textarea

Tags: php

how to show data from database inside text area....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<textarea rows="" cols=""><?php echo $yourdata; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get your data in $data
print  then $data then  and you're done.

$data = "one line\nother line";

```
echo '<textarea>', $data , '</textarea>';
```